# Javascript - selection - identify text node

Tags: javascript, selection

I'm using Javascript Selection methods and want to save user's selection even after refreshing the page. I've added a unique id to **every** html element on the page. After user's selection I save anchorNode id, focusNode and offsets. Then I want to restore the selection using Range and Selection classes. Problem is:
For example if a have

```
<div id="u1">hello <i id="u2">italic</i> word!</div>
```

And user selected *llo italic wor*, anchorOffset will be 2, focusOffset will be 3, because we have 3 text nodes inside of the div. So, how to determine the text nodes? I will have u1 id (parent id) but how to know which text node the offset belongs to? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Serializer module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Serializer-Module) from my [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) library, or the approach it uses, which is explained in the documentation. It looks a little like [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath).

Comment: No, I can't... because while user was absent, text may be changed... Im such case all Serializer data will be broken (because DOM will be little another)

Comment: @Volodymyr: OK. So what can and cannot change between saving and restoring the selection?

Comment: I can save id of the parent tag and offset. For example, if the structure is <div id="u1">some small text</div> I can save baseId u1, baseOffset - begin of the user selection, focusId - u1, focusOffset - end of user selection. Then with these 4 values I can create a Selection object and using Rangy Highlighter plugin highlight the selection. But if the tag has a structure like showed in my question, it doesn't work because it has 3 textNodes and I don't know how to determine which textNode use...

Comment: i'm not going to read your documentation for your random library, rather than you explaining it right here. very simple ask

Comment: @neaumusic: The documentation link was out of date so I've fixed that now. The place for explaining the detail of how a library works is in the library's documentation. Copying and pasting from it seems redundant to me.

Answer (score 0):

We can determine the position if the text Node in the parent div
selectedText - instance of Selection calss

```
 var selectedStartNodeText = selectedText.anchorNode.textContent;
 var startTextNodeId = 0;
 $.each(selectedText.anchorNode.parentNode.childNodes, function(i, n){
        if(n.textContent == selectedStartNodeText) {
                startTextNodeId = i;
        }
 });
```